# Android Adding a new Calendar

Tags: android, api, calendar

I've checked all over for ways to create a new calendar from within an Android app. The only way I've seen is using the new Calendar API in the latest api version, BUT this only seems to work if you use `CalendarContract.ACCOUNT_TYPE_LOCAL`. It won't let you create a Calendar attached to the users Google account, synchronized with `Google Calendar`. It doesn't appear in the calendar list online at [Google Calendar](http://www.google.com/calendar).

```
values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, 
    CalendarContract.ACCOUNT_TYPE_LOCAL);
```

I've tried using the account type from the Account, but this does not work. It doesn't seem to produce any error though. The result comes back fine.

```
values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountType);
```

Here is the full code for adding a new local calendar using the `Calendar API` and `SYNCADAPTER` (account type commented out). Does anyone know if what I'm trying to do is even possible?

```
AccountManager manager = AccountManager.get(context);
Account[] accounts = manager.getAccountsByType("com.google");

String accountName = "";
String accountType = "";

for (Account account : accounts) {
    accountName = account.name;
    accountType = account.type;
    break;
}

ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName);
//values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountType);
values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, CalendarContract.ACCOUNT_TYPE_LOCAL);
values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.NAME, DaysSince.CAL_NAME);
values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME, DaysSince.CAL_NAME);
values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.SYNC_EVENTS, 1);
values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.VISIBLE, 1);
values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_ACCESS_LEVEL, CalendarContract.Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_OWNER);
values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.OWNER_ACCOUNT, accountName);
values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.DIRTY, 1);
values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_TIME_ZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getID());

Uri calUri = CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI;

calUri = calUri.buildUpon()
        .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "true")
        .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName)
        .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountType)
        .build();

Uri result = cr.insert(calUri, values);
```

Comment: Please answer your own question, if your problem is solved. You will get a badge and many will get free/easy help.

Comment: Have you got any solution for your question? I am looking for same. BTW good question.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do it. But since you want to create a calendar linked with your google account, you need Google Calendar API for this (didn't find  a single solution for doing this with Android Calendar Provider). Check below links:

- [Google calendar API for Android](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android)
- [Insert new Google Calendar](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/insert)

Be sure to check their API explorer. Simple **HTTP REQUEST** for creating new calendar:

`POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars?key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

```
{
 "summary": "My new google calendar"
}
```

And it's **RESPONSE**:

```
{
 "kind": "calendar#calendar",
 "etag": "__________etag_val_________",
 "id": "______id_goes_here______@group.calendar.google.com",
 "summary": "My new google calendar"
}
```

After that you should be able to manage this calendar from your Android app with Calendar Provider (after sync).

Comment: Can you elaborate please? What is `YOUR_API_KEY` in your code?

Comment: For Android API authentication proceeds only with [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth). Anyway the 1st [link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android) is still valid and can give you a quick start with Android and Google Calendar API. Speaking of inserting a new calendar with their API check [this](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/insert)