# Android inserting new Calendar Synchronization

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, android-calendar, android-syncadapter

I would create a new calendar in a existing Google account using my custom Android application.
Following some tutorial found here in stack overflow I created the application composed by:
main activity (where I read and manage events), a service file (called CalendarService) and a SyncAdapter.
In the main activity I initialized the service using an Intent:

```
private Intent calendarServiceIntent;
...
calendarServiceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CalendarService.class);
startService(calendarServiceIntent);
```

then I implemented the service in this way:

```
public class CalendarService extends Service{

//private static final Object sSyncAdapterLock = new Object();

private static CalendarSyncAdapter sSyncAdapter = null;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    //synchronized (sSyncAdapterLock) {
        if (sSyncAdapter == null) {
            System.out.println("SERVICE STARTED ON CREATE");
            sSyncAdapter = new CalendarSyncAdapter(getApplicationContext(), true); 
        }
   // }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    System.out.println("SERVICE STARTED BINDER");
    return sSyncAdapter.getSyncAdapterBinder();
}
```

}

Then I implemented the class CalendarSyncAdapter extends AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter as:

```
    public CalendarSyncAdapter(Context context, boolean autoInitialize) {
    super(context, autoInitialize);
}

@Override
public void onPerformSync(Account account, Bundle extras, String authority,
        ContentProviderClient provider, SyncResult syncResult) {
    Uri calUri = CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI;
      ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
      cv.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, "mygoogleaccount@gmail.com");
      cv.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, CalendarContract.ACCOUNT_TYPE_LOCAL);
      cv.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.NAME, "MyCalendar");
      cv.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME, "MyCalendar");
      cv.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_COLOR, Color.RED);
      cv.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_ACCESS_LEVEL, CalendarContract.Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_OWNER);
      cv.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.OWNER_ACCOUNT, "mygoogleaccount@gmail.com");
      cv.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.VISIBLE, 1);
      cv.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.SYNC_EVENTS, 1);

      ContentResolver cr = getContext().getContentResolver();

      Uri creationUri = asSyncAdapter(Calendars.CONTENT_URI, "mygoogleaccount@gmail.com", CalendarContract.ACCOUNT_TYPE_LOCAL );
      Uri created = cr.insert( creationUri, cv );

}



private Uri asSyncAdapter( Uri uri, String account, String accountType )
{
    return uri.buildUpon()
    .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER,"true")
    .appendQueryParameter(Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, "mygoogleaccount@gmail.com")
    .appendQueryParameter(Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, CalendarContract.ACCOUNT_TYPE_LOCAL).build();
}
```

This is a part of the xml file

```
<service android:name=".CalendarService"
android:exported="true">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.content.CalendarSyncAdapter" />
</intent-filter>
<meta-data
android:name="android.content.CalendarSyncAdapter"
android:resource="@xml/calendar_sync_adapter" />
</service>
```

and this is the xml source associated

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sync-adapter xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:contentAuthority="com.android.calendar"
   android:accountType="com.google"
   android:userVisible="true"
/>
```

Obviously all this does not work and the new calendar is created only if I move the code (inside  the method "onPeformSync") in the main activity. Which is the correct solution to create a new calendar using a syncAdapter?
Finally a doubt: there is the possibility to sync the new calendar with Google Calendar?
Thanks in advance

Comment: have you found any solution for this??

Comment: Do You got a solution for this, i am also facing same problem , found a link see if it might help you !! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12566736/android-adding-a-new-calendar